# Column names from MySQL table in the right order

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I am using the following SQL command to get all column names from my table in MySQL:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = 'сведения о фильме' and table_schema = 'videokassety2';
```

It give me all column names in the table 'сведения о фильме', however it sorts the results and gives me the following:

```
ID Компании
Год выпуска
Название фильма
Номер фильма
Основные исполнители
Характер фильма
```

However, I do not need sorting, I need the order in which they appear in the table itself, like the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq9xv.png)

How can I get a list of column_nmaes without any sorting?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The column `ordinal_position` has the original column ordering information:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'сведения о фильме' AND table_schema = 'videokassety2'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```